# auto fails to deduce?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, auto, member-pointers

```
struct test 
{
  void f() {};
};
test t1;

using memfun_t = void (test::*)();
memfun_t mf = &test::f;


auto a1 = &test::f; // OK 
auto a2 = t1.*mf;  // error 
auto a3 = &(t1.*mf); // still no luck
```

Any ideas why this can't be deduced? I would appreciate answers referencing the Standard.

Edit :

I have found a RAD Studio language extension called __closure that appears to be addressing this issue.[1](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Closure) Here is the code :

```
class base {
public:
    void func(int x) {
    };
};

typedef void(base::*pBaseMember)(int);

class derived : public base {
public:
    void new_func(int i) {
    };
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    derived derivedObject;
    void(__closure * derivedClosure)(int);

    // Get a pointer to the ‘new_func’ member.
    // Note the closure is associated with the
    // particular object, ‘derivedObject’.
    derivedClosure = derivedObject.new_func;

    derivedClosure(3); // Call ‘new_func’ through the closure.
    return 0;
}
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use

```
auto a2 = t1.*mf;  // error
```

just like you can't use:

```
auto a2 = t1.f;
```

`t1.f` is not a valid expression. A pointer to a member function cannot be obtained through an instance of the class. Unlike non-member functions, which decay to a function pointer when used like that, member functions don't decay to a member function pointer.

Relevant text from the C++11 Standard:

> **Unary Operators**
>
> ...
>
> 4 A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses. [ *Note:* that is, the expression `&(qualified-id)`, where the `qualified-id` is enclosed in parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to member.” Neither does `qualified-id`, because there is no implicit conversion from a *qualified-id* for a non-static member function to the type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of function type to the type “pointer to function” (4.3). Nor is
>   `&unqualified-id` a pointer to member, even within the scope of the *unqualified-id*’s class. *—end note* ]

Comment: Well that's the question now, isn't it? Why should it not be able to deduce a member function pointer?

Comment: @Lenz, that would be the question if `mf` was not part of the post.

Comment: @Lenz: It cannot deduce a member function pointer because only valid expressions can be deduced and it's not a valid expression. Why isn't it a valid expression? Because those are the rules of C++ member functions and member pointers.

Comment: @R Sahu, t1.*mf is an expression that I can apply (). If it is an expression, to my mind, it should have a type. If it has a type auto should be able to deduce. I am not sure what part of this is not quite clear?

Comment: @Lenz, That's what the standard says. I am not sure why the standard is defined that way. I give the standard developers the benefit of the doubt and hope that they had good reasons to define it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the Standard reference. "Note" appears to be referring to this case. It doesn't make much sense. It says t1.*mf "does not form an expression of type 'pointer to member' ". Why? It looks like a pointer to member to me. If it does not form a pointer to member why is (t1.*mf)() a valid expression?